# How to add a custom JSON-RPC endpoint to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, json-rpc

I'm building an Ethereum private network and I want to make a custom JSON-RPC endpoint.

I've been customizing and adding some things in the go-ethereum source code but I don't know yet where to look to make this and which files would be involved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying different things I found that the answer is very simple:

Just by adding a method in `go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go` let's say "MyMethod", it will map to the JSON-RPC method "eth_myMethod" like so:

```golang
// go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go
func (s *PublicTransactionPoolAPI) MyMethod(ctx context.Context, text string) error {
    log.Info(text)
    return nil
}
```

*RPC call*:

```js
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_myMethod",
    "params": [
        "Hello, World!"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

That will return:

```js
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": null
}
```

And will print `Hello, World!` in the console.

Comment: I have tried but did not work for me, keep getting  "eth_myMethod does not exist/is not available" error message.

Comment: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"the method eth_myMethod does not exist/is not available"}}