# How to add a custom JSON RPC endpoint to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, golang

I would like to add custom RPC method to geth. I found this question:
[How to add a custom JSON-RPC endpoint to geth?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/73106/70443). But it does not work...

What I did:

```
1. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
2. Modified `go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go` file adding new function. 
3. Run docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t goethereum:latest "."
```

Now I have image, from this image I have created `docker-compose.yml` to run network with one bootnode and one miner. Calling from Postman:

```
POST|GET http://localhost:8545
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_myMethod",
    "params": [
        "Hello world!"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

But for the response I get:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "error": {
        "code": -32601,
        "message": "the method eth_myMethod does not exist/is not available"
    }
}
```

Is there any line of code I need to add in order to register this new method to be available trough JSON RPC API?